# How to execute string query

Tags: postgresql

It is known that you can do EXECUTE `SELECT * FROM table1`. But how can I execute **string queries** assuming that the string is valid query for example: `EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM table1;'`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What have you tried, what errors are you getting, what do you want to do, that sort of thing.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 0):

`EXECUTE` is a PL/pgSQL command and cannot be used in plain SQL queries.

You'll have to write a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) to use `EXECUTE`, but the simplest way to do what you seem to want to do is to use [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to return the query results from the function.

You can define the function with [`RETURNS SETOF RECORD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-overview.html#PLPGSQL-ARGS-RESULTS) to avoid having to specify the result columns at function definition time, but then you need to [specify them when you call the function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS).